# Change the levels of a factor variable

Tags: r, variables

**Hello,**
My table df is :

```
  Nr.of.members COD_PAY_CRM  cls1  cls2 
1           342          TZ    S8         
2             1          IT    S3    S4  
3             4          CL    S0    S0      
4             1          AS               
5             6          UA    S4    S8    
6           100          OM   S11    S9    
...
```

cls1 and cls2 are have factor variables with levels S0 S1, S2, .. S10, S11 SX and "" (empty).

When I make tables of frequency of cls1~cls2 with function *cast* or *table*, the display is in the alphabetical order : "" S0 S1 S10 S11 S2 S3 ... 
I tried to reorder it before making the table of frequency with this code :

```
levels(df$cls1)=as.factor(c("S0", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5",  "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "S11", "SX", ""))
```

It changes the display or the column names but not the values, for example at the begining I have

```
 cls1    V1   S0    S1   S10    S11    S2 
1       684895    21   848 6956  11493  64647
2   S0       0 25987   269    3    120   9152
3   S1       0   545  5575  190    235  20561
4   S10      0    31   303 3522   1487   6312
5   S11      0    81   140 1763 157984  42024
6   S2       0 14690 12791 6674  51303 593072   
#V1 is the level "" that have been remane automatically by R
```

and when I change the levels the result is :

```
 cls1       S0   S1    S2   S3    S4    S5 
1   S0   684895   21   848 6956  11493  64647
2   S1       0   25987   269    3    120   9152
3   S2       0   545  5575  190    235  20561
4   S3       0    31   303 3522   1487   6312
5   S4       0    81   140 1763 157984  42024
6   S5       0 14690 12791 6674  51303 593072
```

As you can see it didn't change the display of the value only the name of my variables. 
How can i reorder my factor variables in order to change the display ?

Than you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply overwriting your levels in your approach above.  Try this below.  It should maintain your actual data and reorder your levels as desired.

`df$cls1=factor(df$cls1,levels=c("S0", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5",  "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "S11", "SX", ""))`

I'd also recommend exploring the `forcats` package.  It has a lot of functions to work with in regards to factors and their levels.

Comment: It  didn't work, only S10, S11 and "" was recognized and the other passed to NA

Comment: OK, that suggests the data isn't labeled exactly as provided, perhaps there is trailing white space, i.e. `"S0 " instead of "S0".  Either way you need to provide a reproducible example.  My solution should work for the problem as you've presented it but without anything else to work with I'm unable to debug it further.

Comment: It was a problem frm the type of my initial data, thank you so much !!